# foreach statement doesn't add values to a list

Tags: c#

I don't know why the foreach statement doesn't add values to a List, help

```
foreach (var item in blocklines)
            {
                if (item.Contains(','))
                {
                    List<double> xyz = item.Split(',').Select(double.Parse).ToList();
                }
            }
```

Comment: How do you know it is not adding to the list? What is the input? What the expected output? What is happening or not happening instead?

Comment: You are declaring a list inside the if scope. You must declared outside the foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration of the loop is creating a new list, doing nothing with it, and allowing it to fall out of scope.  If instead you want a single list which is modified in each iteration of the loop and then can be observed after the loop, create only *one* list first and then modify it in the loop:

```
List<double> xyz = new List<double>();
foreach (var item in blocklines)
{
    if (item.Contains(','))
    {
        xyz.AddRange(item.Split(',').Select(double.Parse).ToList());
    }
}
// xyz is now avaiable here
```

Comment: Hi David, David, it worked, but, I have an issue with a for loop:
Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.PointCollection VMM40Points = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.PointCollection(Spatialreference);
            for (int i = 1; i == xyz.Count/3; i += 3)
            {
                VMM40Points.Add(xyz[i - 1], xyz[i], xyz[i + 1]);
            }
but doesn't add any point

Comment: @ErickMorris: Potentially a completely different issue, given that code is entirely unrelated to the code in the question.  This may merit a new question, and certainly after making use of your debugger to observe the specific behavior.